# Doing requests concurrently with Promise.all pushing promises to an array in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, promise

I know it's a long title but it sumarizes what I intend to do. In a certain app I have a form with many different parts that do POST or PATCH requests to an API. The issue is that those calls are being executed inmediately instead of all at the same time when confirming the changes.

The solution I tought of was adding promises to an array and executing them with Promise.all.

I have a working demo with a Parent and Child component in React. Where the parent holds an array of promises state, the child pushes promises and the parent executes Promise.all.

[Github pages demo](https://leimeter-joaquin.github.io/parent-child-state-management/)
[Repo - branch](https://github.com/leimeter-joaquin/parent-child-state-management/tree/stackoverflow-question-promises)

Parent.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Child from "./child";

function Parent() {
  console.log("parent render");
  const [array, setArray] = useState<Array<() => Promise<unknown>>>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("array in parent", array);
  }, [array]);

  const runPromises = () => {
    // Invoke each function to get the promise
    const promises = array.map((func) => func());

    // Execute the all promises concurrently
    Promise.all(promises)
      .then((values) => {
        console.log(values);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>Parent</div>
      <Child array={array} setArray={setArray} />
      <button onClick={runPromises}>Run promises</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default Parent;
```

Child.

```
import { Dispatch, useEffect, useState } from "react";

type Props = {
  array: Array<unknown>;
  setArray: Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<unknown>>;
};

function Child({ array, setArray }: Props) {
  console.log("child render");
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  count;

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("array in child", array);
  }, [array]);

  const addToPromiseArray = () => {
    setCount((oldValue) => oldValue + 1);

    // Function that returns a promise when executed. This is done because fetching is eager when handled inside a new Promise constructor.
    const newPromise = () =>
      // new Promise created to fetch an API.
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fetch("https://picsum.photos/200/300")
          .then((response) => {
            if (response.ok) {
              resolve(response); // Resolving the Promise with the response
            } else {
              reject("Error fetching data"); // Reject the Promise in case of an error
            }
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            reject(error); // Reject the Promise in case of an error
          });
      });

    // Push the new Promise to the promises array to execute them in the parent component.
    setArray((oldValue) => [
      ...oldValue,
      newPromise, // Adding the resolved promise to the array
    ]);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>Child</div>
      <button onClick={addToPromiseArray}>Push to array</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default Child;
```

In the code you will find comments explaining each action taken. The relevant components are located in *src/components/Parent.tsx* and *src/components/Child.tsx*

I want to get an opinion on wether this is a good solution. I managed to push the promises and execute them by wrapping them inside another function that returns the prmise in the child component, and doing a for loop executing the functions, getting the promises and runing them with Promise.all after the fact. It seems odd but it was the only way I found to make this work. Maybe someone with more experience can help. Thanks for your time.

Comment: This is a pretty common pattern; I think you're on the right track. If you have a lot of promises that you'd like to concurrently resolve, using Promise.all() is the way to go.

Comment: Please [post the relevant code as part of your question, not a link to it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) (that will rot - and it's not even linking a specific commit so the repo content will likely change).

Comment: Promises are not "executed". The request is made immediately when you call the function, and all requests in your loop are still made at once. All that `Promise.all` does is to allow waiting for all the results of the concurrent requests.

Comment: @Bergi I'll post the code later today. Thanks for the response.

Comment: I guess your code works fine, and is ok as a pattern, but your terminology and variable names are off. You have an array of functions, not an array of promises. So it should be `runFuncs` not `runPromises`, and `const newFunction` not `const newPromise`, and lots of changes to the comments. Also [avoid the `Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it) around `fetch`, and don't use a separate state for `count` but simply do `const count = array.length`.